# When setting spring cloud data flow (scdf) 2.x as maven dependency of a regular spring boot app, the dataflow local server is not starting

Tags: java

Below are steps :

1. Created a simple spring boot app from spring initializer and
   imported in eclipse
2. Added dependency for scdf (spring cloud dataflow
   server) 2.0.1.RELEASE in project pom , along with other dependencies
   for Oracle jdbc etc defined some properties for in
   application.properties file for oracle connectivity etc
3. Ran the application as Java app (using JDK 1.8)

NOTE: Doing this , so as to
    do lot of easy customization for project/organization needs to get
    deployed into available linux host etc Getting below error in start
    up

****Application Failed to Start
Binding to taget org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundary' to org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundary.CloudFoundaryConnectionProperties failed:

Properties: spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundary.password
Value : null
Reason: must not be null

...............and similar for other properties

The question is , i am simply trying to use the SCDF as local server, why it is still asking for cloudfoundary ?